# Annotation with parameters already filled in

Tags: java, annotations, java-annotations

In the tech stack I'm working with we have an existing Java annotation for our unit tests which gets used like

```
@TeamTest(size = TestSize.Medium, timeout = 5000)
void myTest() {
  // setup and asserts and stuff
}
```

Is there a way to setup a separate annotation that would already have the size and timeout variables stored? Ex:

```
@TeamTest(size = TestSize.Medium, timeout = 5000)
public static @interface MediumTest {}
```

That way I could just do

```
@MediumTest
void myTest() {
  // setup and asserts and stuff
}
```

Comment: Are these annotations part of your codebase? (i.e. not part of an external library)

Comment: The @TeamTest is part of an adjacent team's codebase. I wouldn't be able to modify them in any meaningful way (the annotations support a variety of teams) but can treat like a direct build dependency.